# FileZilla Server encryption algorithm

Tags: openssl, filezilla

I want to change FileZilla encryption algorithm from AES_GCM_256 bit to aes_ccm. I have walked through server's code but cannot figure out where exactly is this happening. I can see that open ssl libs are being used but still I cannot reach the point in code from where cipher method is called for encryption. Can anyone help me locating the point of encryption in filezilla server code? I have compiled the filezilla server code in visual studio 2013. trying to debug but cannot set breakpoints on all locations:( aaaaaah

Additionally, I have gone through openssl 1.0.1h code and I cannot find code for aes_gcm_256 (which is being used by filezilla). Going through documentation doesnot tell me much. I want to know how required encryption cipher (aes_gcm_256) is called from filezilla server code during download and what are the source files in openssl in which aes_gcm_256 algorithm has been implemented?

Comment: All this assumes Filezilla uses OpenSSL... Search Filezilla sources for `SSL_CTX_new`. `SSL_CTX_new` returns a `SSL_CTX*`. To set the ciphers used on a SSL/TLS connection (the `SSL_CTX*` from `SSL_CTX_new`), Filezilla will need to call `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` or `SSL_set_cipher_list`. But don't be surprised if the call to `SSL_{CTX}_set_cipher_list` is *not* made. If its not made, then the default OpenSSL behavior is used (which provides the default cipher suites).

Comment: *"I have gone through openssl 1.0.1h code and I cannot find code for aes_gcm_256"* - I believe its called `AES256-GCM-SHA384` (and friends), not `aes_gcm_256`. See [`ciphers(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) from the OpenSSL docs. There's about 20 cipher suites that use GCM to choose from, but no CCM-related suites.

Comment: thank you so much..that is what I was looking for. I found pSSL_set_cipher_list(m_ssl,"DEFAULT:!DES:!WEAK:!EXP")...as it says it should be default so it was switching to aes_gcm_256..I have manually set my required algorithm and it works fine:)

Comment: regarding open ssl AES-GCM: Yes that is the problem...My real problem was changing the cipher filezilla but as I have looked into openssl lib so now I am curious how aes-gcm is implemented in openssl? I can see source files for different aes modes like aes_cbc, aes_ctr etc but no file for aes_gcm exists!! Is it implemented differently than other modes!! I can see the constant definition in evp but I cannot figureout the implementation flow of AES-GCM...any idea?